# nrwl nx node angular version compatibility

Tags: node.js, angular, version, compatibility, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to start learning nrwl/nx, node, angular. I can't even get through nrwl's simple tutorial. I'm struck on https://nx.dev/l/r/tutorial/07-share-code step. I get the following error:

```
    Error: apps/todos/src/app/app.component.ts:3:22 - error TS2307: 
Cannot find module '@TESTNX02/data' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The offending code is:

```
import { ToDo } from '@TESTNX02/data'
```

I was wondering whether this is caused by incompatibility between nrwl/nx, node, and angular in my setup. How do I ensure that I'm using compatible versions?

Comment: It's not clear how to go about helping you with this. The URL you've pasted doesn't go to a tutorial step any more and manually navigating to the "7 Share Code" step of the tutorial from the nx page doesn't show any code that uses `TESTNX02`. If you're still having difficulties I'd recommend trying to start over again with the new tutorial that is there and provide all details of any issues you encounter within the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

"npx create-nx-workspace@latest" creates the workspace with the latest version of Nx. When you install Angular with the command "npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular" Nx installs the compatible version of Angular. So, no need to worry about version compatibility.

Comment: if this were true, why can I not resolve this constant error of `Unable to resolve @nrwl/node:execute`